# CSS3 JQuery change content of class

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I have the following class:

```
#categories_btn:after {
    content: "+";   
}
```

I am trying to use jquery to toggle this class to show either + or -.  What is the best way to do this?

```
   $('#categories_btn a').click(function(){
     $('aside#left_col #categories').toggle();
   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class that has different `:after` content:

```
#categories_btn.alt:after {
    content: "-";   
}
```

Then toggle this class on the desired element using `toggleClass('alt')`.